# how to create rgbstyle while rendering tif file using geotools?

Tags: java, tiff, geotools

I have a tiff file, and the effect when opened in qgis is very inconsistent with the effect rendered with geotools.

open by qgis
[image]

the imagelab snapshot (Color is obviously distorted).
[image]
the Imagelab source code can be download from here:
https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/_downloads/b1a328d258da28a4e9da534d4aaca37c/ImageLab.java
The key code is the createRGBStyle function, the code has some compilation errors, mainly namespace issues. I will put the modified code in the link below.

The strange thing is that some tiff files have normal effects after being opened with imagelab. what is the reason behind the scene?

[the source tiff file and modified imagelabs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wG30b7BEgLSgt9wpLqYce1Lv6pvhs59b?usp=sharing)

geotools's version: 28.5,29.3,30.1

I used qgis to view the metadata information of the two tiff data and found nothing special.
geotools imagelab render with color error tiff
[image: geotools render error tiff]
geotools imagelab render ok tiff
[image: geotools render ok tiff]

Comment: Looks like the TIFF uses JPEG compressed tiles, and the colors are incorrectly converted from YCC to RGB (they were already RGB and shouldn't have been).

Comment: i have uploaded a new tiff file  which render fine with geotools, I can't see any specific difference between them.

Comment: the compilation issues stem from mixing your GeoTools versions stable is 30.x currently not 28.5 - there were substantial changes see the [blog](https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2023/10/geotools-300-released.html) for details

Comment: One possible issue is that one of your files (the one that fails) is an image/world file pair and the other is a real GeoTiff and they take different routes to the renderer.

Comment: the L21.tfw file just contains data bounds information, very simple. Deleting this file will have the same effect

Comment: i have been tested geotools version 29.3 and 30.1, not difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was found. It was caused by the tiff file not generating an image pyramid. It should also be noted that when generating an image pyramid, you need to use the external mode, which is to generate the external pyramid file of ovr. Otherwise, there will still be problems when rendering with geotools. .
Finally, geotools still has some problems when rendering tiff pyramid images. After zooming in to a certain extent, the color will be distorted.